# Scrape the Data with Rcurl

Tags: r, beautifulsoup, scrapy, rcurl

I want to crawl some data from the following the url using Rcurl and XML.

http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/air_daily/air_dairy.jsp?&lang=

the data range is from "2000-06-05" to "2013-12-30", there're more than 10000 pages.

The elements in this page associated with the data.

```
<form name="report1_turnPageForm" method=post     
action="http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn:80/.../air.../air_dairy.jsp..." style="display:none">
<input type=hidden name=reportParamsId value=122169>
<input type=hidden name=report1_currPage value="1">
<input type=hidden name=report1_cachedId value=53661>
</form>
```

and the link also looks like this

http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/air_daily/air_dairy.jsp?city&startdate=2013-12-15&enddate=2013-12-30&page=31

there're startdate and enddate and page..

then I began to crawl the web.

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
k = postForm("http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/air_daily/air_dairy.jsp?&lang=")
k = iconv(k, 'gbk', 'utf-8')
k = htmlParse(k, asText = TRUE, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

then..I don't know what to do next..and I'm not sure whether I'm on the correct track?

I also tried this

```
k = sapply(getNodeSet(doc = k, path = "//font[@color='#0000FF' and @size='2']"),
       xmlValue)[1:24]
```

It doesn't work..

Could give some suggestions ? Thanks a lot!

Scrapy and beautifulsoup solutions are also strongly welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

If `XML` is sufficient, maybe this would be a starting point:

```
require(XML)

url <- "http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/report/air_daily/air_dairy.jsp?city&startdate=2013-12-15&enddate=2013-12-30&page=%d"
pages <- 2
tabs <- vector("list", length=pages)

for (page in 1:pages) {
  doc <- htmlParse(paste(suppressWarnings(readLines(sprintf(url, 
                                                            page), 
                                                    encoding="UTF-8")), 
                         collapse="\n"))
  tabs[[page]] <- readHTMLTable(doc, 
                                header=TRUE, 
                                which=4)  # readHTMLTable(doc)[["report1"]]
}

do.call(rbind.data.frame, tabs) # output
```

Comment: thanks a lot! @lukeA. I think there're some issues about Chinese character encoding in XML package. All the data returned are some strange character..do you have some suggestions about how to deal with it?